# Automated proof verification of metalogical theorems of first order logic

Tags: logic, automated-theorem-proving

Have any of the metalogical theorems of first order logic, such as the deduction theorem, been formalized and proven in a system such as Coq or HOL? If not, what are the main obstacles to doing so?

Comment: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psztxa/g52ifr/src/Meta.v mentions the deduction theorem

Comment: Far more complicated systems, e.g. NuPRL, have been formalized in Coq and had meta-theorems of various sorts proven. Something like Twelf is particularly geared to such meta-theorems. Proving something like the deduction theorem for FOL is more like something that would be given as a (sizeable) exercise as opposed to the limits of research.

Comment: @DerekElkins If I wanted to formalize and prove the metatheorems that I encounter as I learn first order logic, would you suggest Twelf as a good tool for a beginner to learn?

Comment: @user695931 Probably not. Mostly because being familiar with Coq or Isabelle/HOL would be much more valuable than being familiar with Twelf. If you are going to invest a large amount in time and effort into learning one of these systems, those would be better choices. Coq and Isabelle/HOL also have more resources and better support. No serious proof assistant that I'm aware of has a gentle learning curve.